# deletion of binary tree using new method

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

Actually I was stuck while implementing the deletion of a tree . I deleted the leaf nodes using free() and now the parent would become leaf nodes , and delete those nodes too using recursion . But the problem is leaf node is not getting deleted actually , its still there . And also the method i followed in deletion of tree is as follows

```
void deleteTree(struct node *root)
{
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    {
       free(root);
    }
    else
    {
       if(root->left != NULL)
            deleteTree(root->left);
       if(root->right != NULL)
            deleteTree(root->right);
    }
}
```

This method deleted only the leaf nodes , and the corresponding parent nodes were not deleted . After debugging in XCode I found out that the leaf nodes were not deleted , They were still there.

> So, why this happening ?

Comment: CodeJack to know *`So why this happening ??`'* read @BLUEPIXY's updated answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `deleteTree()` is not good for delete nodes in tree. What you are doing is [preorder traverse in binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) recursively. The node you delete/free from tree will be refereed again when function returns, and hence you are accessing a free node that will cause [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) at run-time.

[Do not access freed memory](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEM30-C.+Do+not+access+freed+memory):

> According to the C Standard, the behavior of a program that uses the value of a pointer that refers to space deallocated by a call to the free() or realloc() function is undefined.

You should choose [Post-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order) to free tree's node. because in post-order traversal you don't access a node that is processed (deleted/free). And your `deleteTree()` function should be something like as follows:

```
void deleteTree(struct node *root){
    if(root == NULL) return;
    deleteTree(root->left);
    deleteTree(root->right);
    free(root);  // node processed and return
}
```

Comment: Cause code of the original bad is clear. It does not cover the conditions required by the branch `if`.

Comment: You should add  `if(root->left != NULL)` before `deleteTree(root->left); ` and `if(root->right != NULL)` before `deleteTree(root->right);` because free don't set to NULL

Comment: I can save one call on it for sure.

Comment: `free` does not set to `NULL` pointer that released, but that the nodes of the terminal is set to `NULL` the request of the program are required to these nodes.

Answer (score 4):

```
void deleteTree(struct node *root)
{
   if (root) {
    deleteTree(root->left);
    deleteTree(root->right);
    free(root);
   }
}
```

Comment: If the tree is empty (root=NULL), you will do free(NULL), which could be OK, but I don't think it looks nice.

Comment: @prreal your previous answer was also correct. Not **??**, I mean because free() a pointer that is NULL is not a problem

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not free the parent nodes on *any level,* all levels except for leaves remain. What you need to do is add `free(root)` after the if statement, at the end of the else statement.